# Need help with this geometry problem involving triangles

Tags: geometry

[image]

(This question came from the MTAP 2019 Grade 9 Eliminations)

The question goes like this:

In the figure, $ \angle ADB = 120^\circ, \angle CDB = 140^\circ, $ and $ AD = CD $. If $ AB  = 3x-6$ and $CB = 24$, what are the range of possible values for $x$?

Now, onto what I've tried: Since  $ AD = CD $, $ \Delta ADC $ is obviously an isosceles: therefore, $ \angle D = 100^\circ, \angle DAC = \angle DCA = 40^\circ $. Beyond that, however, I have no clue how to solve this problem. Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

express $AD=CD$ using the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) for the two triangles $ADB$ and $CDB$

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it? There's this awkward $ cos(140^\circ ) $. I'm still really stumped

Comment: $\cos 140°$ is simply a number that you can approximate as $-0.766.....$

Answer (score 1):

When $AD=DC=0$, then $DB=AB=BC=24$, so we have:

$3x-6=24$ ⇒ $x=10$

When $DB=0$, then $AB=AD=CD=CB=24$, so we get $x=10$, that is $x=10$ is maximum.

$x$ is minimum when triangle DCB is isosceles, then we have:

$\angle DCB=\angle DBC=\frac{180-140}{2}=20^o$

⇒ $AD=CD=DB=\frac{12}{Cos(20)}≈12.77$

Now in triangle ADB we have:

$(3x-6)^2=2 \times 12.77^2- 2\times 12,77^2 . Cos(120)$

⇒ $(3x-6)^2=3\times (12.77)^2$ ⇒ $x≈9.3$

This is minimum for x. So we can write:

$AD=DC=[(0), (12.77)]$⇒ $x=[(10), (9.3)]$

$AD=DC=[(12.77), (24)]$⇒ $x=[(9.3), (10)]$